# spring integration kafka outbound adapter producer channel update metadata

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

```xml
    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter sync="false" 
        kafka-template="kafkaTemplate" id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" 
        topic="learning-topic" channel="KafkaAdapterChan" 
        send-failure-channel="FailureChan">
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <bean id="kafkaTemplate" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="xyz:9092" />
                        ... <!-- more producer properties -->
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Above sample works fine for happy path. But when the kafka cluster is restarted, i see the first message after the restart fails with an error "not a leader"...requesting to update metadata.

Once the metadata got updated for the first message after restart, later messages are published correctly. So i am looking for if there is any way i can reinstantiate or update metadata for the kakfa producer outbound channel adapter when there is a kafka cluster restart?

Comment: What version Kafka, Spring Integration Kafka? Please show some logs; I see no such issues with the current versions; I send a message once per minute; restart the broker; see some errors in the logs while it is down `Broker may not be available.`; some errors while the broker is coming up `Error while fetching metadata` but then the next send is successful.

Comment: Confluent kafka 5.1.1, spring-integration-kafka: 3.1.3.RELEASE.

Comment: Try with a newer version of Confluent - I tested with Kafka 2.4.1 (which would be Confluent 5.4.1, I think). I used SIK 3.2.1 too.

Comment: Confluent kafka 5.1.1, spring-integration-kafka: 3.1.3.RELEASE. Logs: [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer -1]:  Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition **** due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException. This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.. Going to request metadata update now.

Comment: so here are the steps i followed. 1. Produced messages with producer1 app successfully. 2.Stopped kafka cluster. 3. Seeing errors with producer1 app. 4. Started kafka cluster. 5.No more errors in producer1 app till the message is published. 6. Just to ensure if kafka cluster is fully up created new producer2 app and posted successfully. 7. BUT I STILL SEE this error for first message from producer1 app, later every message is being posted correctly.

Comment: tried with confluent kafka 5.5.0(which is latest and still the same issue), tried with cloudera kafka as well and the issue still persists. I have one way to handle this exception and retry, but looking for some better way to handle this error.

Comment: Explains why I didn't see it (I only had one broker for my test). See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have one way to handle this exception and retry, but looking for some better way to handle this error.

Have you tried setting the `ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG`?

You can also add a [Retry Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain) to the adapter and the framework will perform the retries.

You can set `sync="true"` on the adapter so the exception is thrown on the calling thread and the retry advice will perform the retry.

Otherwise you'll need your own retry logic on the `FailureChan`.

Comment: If the error is coming back asynchronously, you need `sync=true` to use the retry advice.

Comment: Thank you will try the above options, also just checking if  there is a way to manually trigger to refresh kafka producer connection or to trigger metadata update, probably will expose that method(if exists) in jmx?

Comment: Sync is not recommended for high-volume apps. You can call `reset()` on the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` (if you somehow know the cluster is bounced). The next send will use a new `Producer`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I have a health check code configured to know that kafka was bounced back. So I will try this reset option.